# ¿Qué pasa si respondo una pregunta a la que yo mismo puse recompensa?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

Sucede que hay una pregunta que no ha sido resuelta a la que le han puesto como recompensa 100 puntos.

Mi duda es si yo fuera el autor de la misma pregunta, y nadie me ayuda, o me da la solución esperada, y yo sigo trabajando por mi cuenta buscando así una solución y la obtengo, la comparto, y demuestro que la autoría de dicha solución es mía, entonces ¿qué sucede con los 100 puntos que ofrecí en la pregunta?

Comment: la recompensa queda en nada ya que no te puedes recompensarte tu mismo, hay muchos casos como el que mencionas en el que preguntas con recompensas hay sido resueltas por la misma persona que posteo la pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los puntos se pierden.

Está explicado en la ayuda, [¿Qué es una recompensa? ¿Cómo puedo iniciar una?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (*énfasis mío*):

> Simplemente haz clic en el botón de otorgar recompensa que hay junto a cada respuesta para otorgarla permanentemente al autor de la misma. (**No puedes otorgar una recompensa a tu propia respuesta**<sup>[1]</sup>.)
>
> Si no otorgas tu recompensa en 7 días (más el periodo de gracia), la respuesta más votada publicada tras el ofrecimiento con una puntuación mínima de 2 recibirá la mitad del importe de la recompensa. Si hay dos respuestas o más que cumplan los criterios y tengan la misma puntuación, la respuesta más antigua se llevará la recompensa. **Si no hay ninguna respuesta que cumpla los criterios, la recompensa quedará sin otorgar**.
>
> Si la recompensa fue iniciada por el propietario de la pregunta, y el mismo acepta una de las respuestas publicadas durante el periodo de la recompensa, y la recompensa expira sin un otorgamiento explícito, entonces asumimos que al iniciador de la recompensa le gustó la respuesta que aceptó, y otorgamos a dicha respuesta el importe completo de la recompensa cuando ésta expira.

<sup><sub>[1] En la ayuda dice "pregunta", pero es un error. Quiere decir "respuesta".</sub></sup>

Es decir que no puedes otorgarte una recompensa a ti mismo. Sólo si otra persona hubiese ofrecido la recompensa en tu pregunta, entonces sí podría asignártela.

Como en todas las recompensas, una vez que son ofrecidas, la reputación no se puede recuperar, sin excepciones.

Más información:

- [¿Qué es una recompensa? ¿Cómo puedo iniciar una?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)
- [Ofrecer Recompensas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)